# Pros and cons of different core pool sizes vs max pool sizes for ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, jvm, threadpool

I'm setting up a service with a ThreadPoolExecutor, and it's currently using a fixed thread pool by setting core pool size == max pool size of 64. It's working fine but I'm wondering if I can tune it as I know most of my requests only need 1 thread to finish (although some may definitely take the entire 64).

If I set core pool size to 1 and max size to 64, then I feel I'm going to being utilizing my memory 99% better, but I also think that there's going to be some overhead involved when a request comes in that needs more than 1 thread to finish (the thread pool will have to create new threads once the queue is full). Should I be worried about this overhead, or is the more efficient memory utilization worth it?